# FreeRTOS freezes

Tags: c, real-time, freertos

I have a simple FreeRTOS programm and basically I need to calculate the time it takes to run for a different number of iterations.
The problem is that it just freezes and doesn't execute anymore though the iterations are not complete yet and I need it to succesfully come to vTaskEndScheduler() to terminate so I can calculate the time correctly. What could be a reason?
[Freeze screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjiWI.png)

```
  void Task1() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
        printf("This is task 1 ");
        printf("Iteration number ");
        printf("%d", i);
        printf("\n");
        vTaskDelay(100);
    }
    vTaskEndScheduler();
};

void Task2() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("This is task 2 ");
        printf("Iteration number ");
        printf("%d", i);
        printf("\n");


        vTaskDelay(100);
    }
    vTaskEndScheduler();
};



void main_blinky(void)
{
    enableFlushAfterPrintf();

    xTaskCreate(Task1, (signed char*) "t1", 100, NULL, 1, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(Task2, (signed char*) "t2", 100, NULL, 1, NULL);


    vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just at a glance, without knowing anything about your system, I would GUESS printf() is causing the problem.  How is it implemented?  Is it thread safe?  Do your tasks have enough stack space for its stack requirements, which can be substantial depending on the library you are using: https://freertos.org/Stacks-and-stack-overflow-checking.html

See notes in the (free but somewhat out of date) book (https://freertos.org/Documentation/RTOS_book.html) ref printf.

Answer (score 2):

You must first choose appropriate stack for task and to be sure it's accessible by heap size in run-time, after that then i think
problem may is in printf() method and the way that's implemented.

Comment: Is this not just a subsequent copy of the other answer?

Comment: A little bit different, I note to check static heap size value of microcontroller before compile time, if not configure correctly this error could be happen. @Richard